# Can GPS be used by more than 1 app at a time

Tags: ios, gps, geolocation, multitasking

I'm looking at various apps which use GPS tracking, and was wondering if more than 1 app at a time was able to gain access to the GPS data?

For example I might want to use one app with route planning for cross country running in order to know where I should be going, and a second app to record where I actually went, and my speeds/splits/averages etc.

Because the apps are using the Background service for location data, does this limit which app is getting the data?  Only 1 music app at a time can play in the background, is the location background service different?

I would test this myself, but the apps I am looking at are not free, and I don't want to pull the trigger if I cannot use them as I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, GPS can be used by more than one app at a time. I frequently use Runkeeper in the background for tracking my movement, and Zombies Run or Geocaching in the foreground. I've never had any issues with any of them not getting the data.

Comment: Thanks @Lizzan - *Zombies, Run!* was the app I had in mind at the 2nd app, but I didn't want to make the question too specific to that app :)  I'll be using Endomondo rather than Runkeeper, but same principal

Comment: @stuffe Have fun with the zombies, I love that app! =)